# Meteor: How do i dynamically addClass to the TD while constructing the Table Template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have requirement where in need to display the table of which tbody will be dynamic.

Below JSON comes from the helper function of Template as a return.

length of this object will equal to Number of Rows. Number of Cols are fixed, but the column (i.e TD) background should change to either Red/Green Based on the time and Status you see below.

For Eg: in the Below JSON you see Time 11 and 12 and Status as "In-Use" (Green), "Idel" (Red), based on this my columns (11th and 12th Column) background should be made as either Green or Red.

```
[{
    "time": [11, 12],
    "status": ["In-Use", "Idle"],
    "name": "Book1"
   }, {
    "time": [12, 13, 14],
    "status": ["Idle", "In-Use"],
    "name": "Book2"
   }]
```

Is is this possible to do in meteor Template ? I am unable to figure out how this can be done.

Below is the Template i have come up So far :

```
<table class="table" >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="Name"></th>
            <th scope="col">06:00</th>
            <th scope="col">07:00</th>
            <th scope="col">08:00</th>
            <th scope="col">09:00</th>
            <th scope="col">10:00</th>
            <th scope="col">11:00</th>
            <th scope="col">12:00</th>
            <th scope="col">13:00</th>
            <th scope="col">14:00</th>
            <th scope="col">15:00</th>
            <th scope="col">16:00</th>
            <th scope="col">17:00</th>
            <th scope="col">18:00</th>
            <th scope="col">19:00</th>
            <th scope="col">20:00</th>
            <th scope="col">21:00</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>


        <tbody>
          {{#each getHistory}}
          <tr>
            <td class="Name">{{name}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

          </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

One Solution is Write a CSS red and Green with background image property then add those Class those TD, but how do i add them while constructing the table inside template ? is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? You are not showing any attempt of solving the problem yourself.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I think i was not clear in my question, anyway i would want to use addClass to those 11th and 12th TD's , and the Css i would write background: red/green. So the actual question is how do i add the class based on time and status array ?? or is there anyway to do this if we can't write addClass inside Template ?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation:

https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-dynamic-templates/

The short answer:

`{{> Template.dynamic template=myTemplate}}`

To set a class Dynamically, which seems to be the question, you can do:

`<div class="my_static_class {{my_dynamic_class}}"></div>` and declare `my_dynamic_class` as a helper.

Comment: I think i was not clear in my question, anyway i would want to use addClass to those 11th and 12th TD's inside the Template , and the Css i would write background: red/green. So the actual question is how do i add the class based on time and status array ? or is there anyway to do this if we can't write addClass inside Template ?

Comment: You can use {{variable}} inside a `<div class="whatever {{my_dynamic_class}} other_class"></div>`

Comment: Yes but to assign that i need to check time and status array values, time : [11, 12] and status ["In-Use","Idle"], for the 11th column set status as In-Use and for 12th column set Status as "Idle", how do i do this comparison ? how do i fetch for 11th , In-Use is the Status ?

Comment: So you do that in your helper function, you have the local scope data to look it up.

Comment: Dint get you ? My helper function is returning that JSON object.

Comment: you have an array of array, you need a nested template

Answer (score 1):

Finally Created the Table Structure in the helper itself and returned the HTML

```
 var htmlTxt = [];
  for(i in historyData){
     htmlTxt.push('<tr id='+historyData[i].name+'>');
     htmlTxt.push('<td class="name">'+historyData[i].name+'</td>');
     var time = historyData[i].time;
     var status = historyData[i].status;
     for(i=1; i<=16;i++){
         var index= $.inArray(i, time);
         if(index == -1){
          htmlTxt.push('<td class="orange"></td>');
         }else{
          htmlTxt.push('<td class='+status[index]+'></td>');
         }
     }
     htmlTxt.push('</tr>');
  }
```

In Template

```
{{{getHistory}}}
```